# Preventing browser caching after web app release: change how ASP.NET MVC3 converts virtual URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, spark-view-engine

I'd like to prevent browser caching of JavaScript, CSS, and image files for a given release of my software.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 with the Spark view engine, and I believe I can do this by appending a custom query string parameter to image, script, and stylesheet URLs rendered using the virtual paths in every instance where this is done.  As in, `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/path/to/script.css"></script>` would be rendered as `<script type="text/javascript" src="/myApplication/path/to/script.css?2.3.0"></script>`.

Is this something that can be done?  Am I on the right track, or is there something else that I can do?

Thanks!

**edit**

I was looking at ETags in IIS, and this seems like it'll do the job just fine.  I did a little testing, and it seems to work.  Does that seem like reasonable solution?

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track. Just append a version number to your static resources and when you change them increment this number.

You could automate this process. It is a good practice to combine your static resources into a single file to avoid multiple requests from the client browser. It is during this process that you could add either a version number or simply the hash of the resulting file. This way if the resulting file changes the hash will also change.

For example the [Web Optimization framework](http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization) is something that you may checkout and which automates those tasks.

So once you have installed the `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` NuGet in your application you could define your bundles in `Application_Start`:

```
var bundles = BundleTable.Bundles;
bundles.Add(
    new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
);
```

and then inside your views reference by name:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

When you are running in Release mode (`debug="false"` in your web.config) this will render as:

```
<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=wBUqTIMTmGl9Hj0haQMeRbd8CoM3UaGnAwp4uDEKfnM1"></script>
```

This framework is extremely powerful as it allows you to combine multiple static resources into a single bundle and it will also minify them reducing bandwidth consumption to strict minimum. It also takes care of caching those static resources and appending a version number based on the contents. So if your original content changes, the generated version number will change as well evicting it from client browsers cache.

And this framework ships with ASP.NET MVC 4 so one day when you upgrade your application you won't have to change anything as this is the default mechanism for handling static resources now.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've added a different option to my question.  Do ETags seem like they'd work for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely one approach but using the [query string as the cache buster isn't the best idea.](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/)

The other approach is to put a timestamp in the url for the browser and then rewrite that server side.

E.g. using the [url rewrite extension](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) create a rule something like:

```
<rule name="AutoVersioningOfCSSAndJS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)\.[\d]{8}\.(css|js)$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.{R:2}" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
</rule>
```

Then render your tag with an 8 digit timestamp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/path/to/script.20121010.css"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I've added a different option to my question.  Do ETags seem like they'd work for this?  Thanks!